# javascript unexpected token . with `{}.toString()`

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

My question is why following is incorrect

```
function hello () {
    {}.toString();//Unexpected token .
}
```

But correct with `return`:

```
function hello () {
    return {}.toString();
}
```

No idea how parser works for the incorrect version, is `{}` treated as `BlockStatement`? If yes, then why?

Thanks for detail explaination

Comment: More syntactically correct examples: `var x = {}.toString(); ({}).toString(); ({}.toString()); false || {}.toString();` So your guess is probably right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> No idea how parser works for the incorrect version, is {} treated as BlockStatement?

Exactly.

> ...why?

Purely because that's the way the grammar is designed. `{` would be ambiguous between starting a block and starting an object initializer when the parser is expecting a statement (which [it is there](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluatebody)), so the grammar says it starts a block. Thus, `{` starts a block, `}` ends it, and the `.` doesn't make sense because the parser is expecting a statement (or a closing `}` for the function body).

But in the second example. because the `{` is after `return`, the parser is [expecting an expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-ReturnStatement) (not a statement), so `{` starts an object initializer.

Anything to put the parser in a state where it's expecting an expression will make it treat that `{` as the beginning of an object initializer. Parentheses are commonly used in that case:

```
function hello() {
    ({}).toString();
}
```

Of course, that function doesn't do anything, because you're not using the result of `toString`...

Comment: Thanks @T.J. , you just saved me. It almost killed me even i have some assumptions. Really appreciate your help